# Invalid value for Integer(): "\x17" mapi pst

Tags: ruby, mapi, pst

Hi I am trying to create a PST reader application of Outlook with Ruby ruby-msg.

I have setup the repository and trying to run the code and it alsways shows the following error

```
lib/mapi/pst.rb:167:in `%': invalid value for Integer(): "\x17" (ArgumentError)
```

My Code is as follows

```
 require 'mapi/pst'

pst = Mapi::Pst.new open('/ruby-msg-master/backup.pst')

p pst.header
```

Unable to find the solution what to do so that the issue resolved

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need Ruby 1.8.7, see this bug [report](https://github.com/packages/ruby-msg/issues/13).

> Sorry at this point ruby 1.9 is not supported

So anything newer than `1.9`, including `2.3`, probably isn't supported either.

Looking at the code, only 1997 and 2003 seem to be supported.

Them gem is probably too old, and you might want to look for another tool (possibly in another language) to convert your `pst` to a plain text format (e.g. `xml` or `csv`).

Comment: i am using ruby 2.3

Comment: when i am using 1.8.7 it shows Could not find a valid gem 'mapitool' (>= 0) in any repository